# React Material ui beta datepicker format

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I can't figure out how to change format for datepicker field.
For user it shows MM/DD/YYYY and I want to show YYYY-MM-DD. Cant find any info in docs so maybe someone knows how to change format?
My component code looks like

```
<Field
name='date'
component={TextField}
type='date'/>
```

Comment: Can you add a link to the material-ui component that you are using. Field seems to be an import from redux-form and not material-ui

Comment: https://material-ui-next.com/demos/pickers/#date-amp-time-pickers this is material ui example, its using TextField with type 'date'

Answer (score 0):

You can pass desired format date in as value prop in your DatePicker component.
https://jsfiddle.net/mu5r94m6/4/

`<DatePicker hintText="Pick your date" value={new Date(2007,11, 5)}/>`

Comment: There is no DatePicker component in Material ui beta